# C# Linq Search by a list into a linq

Tags: c#, linq, contain

Objects:

```
ticketTypeRep = new TicketTypeRepository();
packageRep = new PackageRepository();
```

The data comes from a this list searched by the user:

```
var pases = ticketTypeRep.Fetch()
    .Where(x => x.VTP_NOMBRE_PASE.ToUpper().Trim().Contains(searchString.ToUpper().Trim()))
    .Select(x => new { id = x.VTP_COD_TIPOPASE}).ToList();
```

Im trying to use that data as a list to search every item in another list

```
var packageWithPase = packageRep.Fetch()
    .Where(x => x.PKG_TICKETTYPE.Trim().Contains("21"))
    .Select(x => new { id = x.PKG_SEQID, name = x.PKG_NAME, state = x.PKG_STATE, details = x.PKG_SEQID, edit = x.PKG_SEQID })
    .OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
```

The thing is that "21" have to be the result of the first list named pases and not a simple string.

Search by a list into a linq I guess.

Comment: I've formatted your code snippets but in doing so have introduced syntax errors (\*\* scattered throughout). You should probably review the code in your question (FYI, indent by four spaces to create a code block in Markdown)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to do the comparison other way round like:

```
passes.Contains(x.PKG_TICKETTYPE.Trim())
```

Remember this is not `String.Contains` instead it is [Enumerable.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.95).aspx)
So your query would be:

```
var packageWithPase = packageRep.Fetch()
                        .Where(x => passes.Contains(x.PKG_TICKETTYPE.Trim())
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            id = x.PKG_SEQID, 
                            name = x.PKG_NAME, 
                            state = x.PKG_STATE, 
                            details = x.PKG_SEQID, 
                            edit = x.PKG_SEQID
                        }).OrderBy(x => x.name)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks Habib, I will this this into the:
var packageWithPase = packageRep.Fetch().Where(x => passes.contains(x.TICKETTYPE.trim())

Comment: @Roberto2790, yes exactly. I have used the same query as in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want but it looks like you want records where `pases` contains the `PKG_TICKETTYPE` value, which would be:

```
var packageWithPase = packageRep.Fetch()
                                .Where(x => pases.Contains(x.PKG_TICKETTYPE.Trim())
                                .Select...
```